# Refresh button instead pager in views

Tags: 7, views, paging

Recently I developed a cg related image gallery with drupal, here: http://cgart.ir/en.

top rated images displayed in quicktabs and provided by views. I need a refresh button instead pager. currently I theme next link as refresh button and hide previous link.

how can I add refresh button in views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is hooking into the pager function and changing its functionality in that page.

I would also recommend using mini pager instead of pager since its much shorter and easier to manipulate.
take a look  [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7)
and [here](http://drupal.org/node/503062)